# Mobile Theme CSS doesn't load correctly. CSS fetched from media/css folder instead?

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I run magento 1.9.1.0 and my main theme is located at

```
skin/frontend/rwd/maintheme
```

now I want to use a mobile theme which is located at

```
skin/frontend/mobile/newtheme
```

I have added the appropriate exceptions in Design but the CSS for the mobile theme is fetched as

```
media/css/newtheme/css/style-ssl_1_cp.css
```

and not from the

```
skin/frontend/mobile/newtheme/css/style.css.
```

This causes some elements of the theme to break. Fonts etc are not displaying correctly.

I have verified the folder permissions and the actual file style.css is present as well.

Merge CSS is set to NO as well.

How can I make the CSS load from `skin/frontend/mobile/newtheme/css` and not `from media/css/newtheme`

**Here is a screenshot of current settings:**
[image: Here is a screenshot of current settings:]

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the css stylesheet in your mobile theme?  Are you using add item method with skin_css using the following snippet?

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/style.css</name><params/></action>
```

Comment: Yes that's right. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems related to the Diglin_UIOptimization module. I just ran into this on a project and tracked the ssl_1_cp filename down to the code in Diglin_UIOptimization_Helper_Data.

```
$suffixFilename = (Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure())?'-ssl':'';
$suffixFilename.= '_'.Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$name = substr ( $name, 0, strpos($name, '.' . $type) );
$name = $name . $suffixFilename .'_cp.'.$type;
```

I disabled the module and the issue went away. There was likely a configuration or file permission issue that was causing this module to not behave properly, but I didn't hunt this down any further as this is an old project that is no longer live.

In my case, this module was also creating files of the given name with the ssl_1_cp suffix, but each file was 0 bytes. Maybe it was an issue with reading the original source file.